# Ionic maps inside ion-list using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I have an requirement in IONIC 1.0 using Angular 1.0 wherein I have to list address of members registered with their location in MAPS, I have managed making list with address now I am stuck at MAPS i.e. how can I display maps using ng-repeat in my ion-list.

I have searched a lot and found a solution to integrate google maps API and place a div in a view and make it as a map, but I want it to be dynamic with ng-repeat in my list

Comment: You means you need to display maps in list? like if in list have 10 user need to display 10 maps with user addresses?